# What tool to use to monitor network issues?

Tags: networking, monitoring

I need a network analysis tool that can find if there are some issues regarding:

- packet transmission
- sessions
- any other stuff is welcome.

I'm connected to the appliance I need to check with a cross cable, so I have to check the traffic client-side. It would be great if it could have a gui and/or multiplatform.

Comment: I was thinking of ntop, but it looks like you need some sort of software cable tester...  Have you tried wireshark?

Comment: Actually no, I'm not so proficient with Wireshark. Can it analyze packet losses and other network issues? Grazie :)

Comment: Here http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/5675/how-to-analyse-througput-packet-loss-rtt-rather-than-go-through-the-graph-of-built-in-feature-of-wireshark they mention the tcp.analysis.lost_segment feature and another couple tricks about RTT. Prego :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) might be what you're looking for. To analyse packet loss you should isolate the session/stream and append "and tcp.analysis.lost_segment" to the automatically generated filter. If you see packets there then it's likely there's packet loss.